# Not able to query results on AWS cloud-watch using filterLogEvents() function in my node js code

Tags: node.js, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

If I am trying to query with empty string on aws log groups with function `filterLogEvents` then I am able to fetch the results but when I'm trying with some query string like "display message" it retrieving  as empty array events.